# Set the position of blocks in beamer presentations

Tags: beamer, block

I am writing a `beamer` presentation and I want a block at the same position in each frame. This is the code:

```
\documentclass[notes=show,beamer]{beamer}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{multimedia}
\usepackage{graphics}

\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{10}
\usetheme{Boadilla}


\begin{document}

\title{Models}

\maketitle


\begin{frame}


\begin{block}{Definition}
\begin{equation*}
\boldsymbol{X}=\left\{ 
\begin{array}{ccccc}
\\ 
\\ 
\\\ 
\\ 
\end{array}%
\right. 
\end{equation*}
\end{block}

\bigskip example

\end{frame}


\begin{frame}

\begin{block}{Definition}
\begin{equation*}
\boldsymbol{X}=\left\{ 
\begin{array}{ccccc}
\\ 
\\ 
\\\ 
\\ 
%
\end{array}
\right. 
\end{equation*}
\end{block}

\textsl{Types of models}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{ll}
\textbf{1} &  \\ 
&  \\ 
2 &  \\ 
&  \\ 
3 & 
\end{tabular}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

But with this, code the block "Definition" in the second and in the third frames has a different position. Is there a way to keep the position of the block fixed?

Comment: On each slide or on each frame? They are different things. You are using two frames, but it seems that you simply need one frame with two slides using overlays.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina On each frame. I need the block in the same position in the two frames

Answer (score 2):

Using the frame positioning option `[t]` with frames 2 and 3 will make the two frames start at the same vertical position (top). You can deliberately add some extra vertical space before the frame starts to better manage the visual appearance.

```
\documentclass[notes=show]{beamer}    
\usepackage{amsfonts,lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{multimedia}
\usepackage{graphics}

\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{10}
\usetheme{Boadilla}    

\begin{document}    
\title{Models}    
\maketitle    

\begin{frame}[t]
\vspace{2em}

\begin{block}{Definition}
\begin{equation*}
\boldsymbol{X}=\left\{ 
\begin{array}{ccccc}
\\ 
\\ 
\\\ 
\\ 
\end{array}%
\right. 
\end{equation*}
\end{block}

\bigskip example

\end{frame}    

\begin{frame}[t]
\vspace{2em}

\begin{block}{Definition}
\begin{equation*}
\boldsymbol{X}=\left\{ 
\begin{array}{ccccc}
\\ 
\\ 
\\\ 
\\ 
%
\end{array}
\right. 
\end{equation*}
\end{block}

\textsl{Types of models}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{ll}
\textbf{1} &  \\ 
&  \\ 
2 &  \\ 
&  \\ 
3 & 
\end{tabular}    
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]